# what is a verifiable example of how to trigger a `is_copy` flag?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the `pd.DataFrame` `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(-1, 4),
                  list('abcd'), list('wxyz'))
```

What actions result in a `is_copy` flag?
I've identified two below.  What else should I include?

```
eval_list = ["df.is_copy",
             "df[:].is_copy",
             "df.loc[:].is_copy",
             "df.iloc[:].is_copy",
             "df[['w', 'x']].is_copy",
             "df[df.columns].is_copy"]

fstr = "{:<22s} -> {}".format

for e in eval_list:
    print(fstr(e, bool(eval(e))))

df.is_copy             -> False
df[:].is_copy          -> True
df.loc[:].is_copy      -> False
df.iloc[:].is_copy     -> False
df[['w', 'x']].is_copy -> True
df[df.columns].is_copy -> False
```

Comment: How about a boolean index?